# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery ; Browserify, Laravel Elixir

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm, browserify, laravel-elixir

I am trying to load bootstrap.js using browserify, Laravel elixir. I use npm to install the packages. Everything seems good but when i try to load my page is shows **"Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"**. I have googled lot but didn't find any solution that works. Here is my codes :

**resources/assets/js/app.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap-sass'
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "prod": "gulp --production",
        "dev": "gulp watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
        "laravel-elixir-vueify": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^2.2.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified your question. The elixir tag which you picked refers to the Elixir programming language not elixir as in laravel.  I've added the correct tag for you.

Comment: No worries.  Just thought you might wonder why I retagged the question.

Comment: yes.. bro can u help me out from my problem??

Comment: Sorry - - know next to nothing about that.

Comment: ah!! ok.. ty to correct me :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have come up with the following approach :

instead of using :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

use :

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```